# How to limit records considered in a nested select within a join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Curious to see if there is a way to write the following T-SQL statement (this one errors with cannot bind TableA in the nested select.)  Removing the error line seems to consider all records from TableB then performs the join.

```
select *
from TableA A
    join (
        select TableAid, TableBinfo
        from TableB
        where TableB.TableAid = A.TableAid -- error line
        group by TableAid, TableBinfo
    ) B on
        A.TableAid = B.TableAid
where A.TableAid = 123
```

Is the following SQL the best I can hope for?

I'd really like to limit the distinct comparison to just the one column in the one table rather than all the columns I select. I don't control the database and it doesn't have indexes on anything but primary keys.

```
select A.TableAid, B.TableBinfo
from TableA A
    join TableB B on
        A.TableAid = B.TableAid
where A.TableAid = 123
group by A.TableAid, B.TableBinfo
```

Comment: Actually first and second select are same. What about using DISTINCT instead?

Comment: Distinct vs Group By should be identical, but I've seen our queries take longer with Distinct probably because of their construction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example looks like you're trying to do an APPLY over a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *
    FROM TableA a
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT t.TableBInfo
            FROM TableB t
            WHERE a.TableAId = b.TableBId
            GROUP BY b.TableBInfo
    ) b
    WHERE a.TableAId = 123
```